# Can't enter to BIOS after debian install - black screen

Tags: boot, partitioning, bios, grub

I have Acer Aspire laptop with Windows 10. Recently I've installed Debian 9 in a different partition and everything went fine. The second time I tried to boot into BIOS I got a black screen with a dash on it.

Also I can't boot grub because Windows Boot Manager boots first (this is why I want to enter the BIOS).

Windows 10 boots just fine.

Comment: Try this: Remove battery, unplug laptop, hold the start button for at least 30 seconds, then replace battery and plug in. If this doesn't help, then follow the procedures in [article1](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html), followed if necessary by [article2](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/access-bios-windows-10).

Comment: when you log into windows 10 is your computer set up for fast boot? if you are able to go through a normal windows 10 boot sequence then I would recommend going into windows 10 and disabling fast boot. This *should* give you the option to enter the bios by pressing a key instead of fast booting to your windows 10 log in screen. I had to disable this so I could get into my bios to boot from USB once. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some research and this same issue has come up in different forums.  It appears that one of the issues that you can run into is the GRUB loader causing this problem.  Here is an [article](http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/09/05/how-to-delete-grub-files-from-a-boot-efi-partition-in-windows-10/) referenced in [this thread](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/527652/cant-access-to-bios-on-black-screen-white-dash) that describes your issue.  The first article describes how to remove the GRUB loader to allow you to get access to the BIOS.  This won't fix the dual boot issue but might get you closer to a stable starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: Remove battery, unplug laptop, hold the start button for at least 30 seconds, then replace battery and plug in.

If this doesn't help, then follow the procedures :

[Getting to the UEFI Firmware Settings from inside Windows](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/access-bios-windows-10)
Go to PC settings > Update & security > Recovery > Restart Now > Troubleshoot > Advanced options > UEFI Firmware Settings > Restart.
The system should restart and take you to the BIOS, where you may reset some
settings that may be troublesome.

And if this fails, use the big gun :
[Run Startup Repair in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: The battery in my laptop is non-removable what to do in this case? About the other options I tried the first but it didn't work, I haven't tried the second tho.

Comment: In some laptops the battery is not detachable and is not serviceable by the user. However, Acer sometimes provides on these models a special switch inside a pin hole that you can long press for 5 - 6 seconds using a needle or a paperclip and it simulates removal and re-insertion of the battery.